# Should I ask the developer to data tags for a react webpage I need to test?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, ui-automation

I am writing an automation script in Cypress for testing one of our web applications. From what I can see, most of the elements only have class attributes in the HTML which are randomly assigned based on the render order by React.

Here is a sample image:

[image]

As there are no other fields other than the CSS for most of the fields, I have to rely on the XPath which makes it very cumbersome and makes the tests flaky. Also I loved the selector playground in Cypress which doesn't work natively with XPath.

So here are some of my questions:

1. Should I just use the XPath for most of my Cypress locations?
2. Should I ask the developer to add `data-test` or `data-cy` tags so that the locators can be identified and used very easily?
3. As I intend to use this in production, is there any significant security risk in keeping data tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special attributes for test identification are recommended by Cypress, are easiest from the perspective of writing your tests, but there are drawbacks

- how many places are there where you need to put a `data-cy`?
- do you know where they should go, or will you have to keep asking for more as testing progresses
- is there a concern about production bundle size
- is there a concern about source code clutter

You don't necessarily need to use xpath, Cypress has a huge number of Traversal commands, summarized here [Examples of traversing DOM elements in Cypress](https://example.cypress.io/commands/traversal)

e.g siblings(), parents(), next(), find(), filter()

Probably a good start is to add data-cy attributes at the logical "top" element of a component e.g header, menu, and use Traversal commands to work within them.